# How to retrieve process in interuptible sleep (S+) or other state?

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to retrieve these or do the processes have to be killed?

```
user    31897  0.1  0.0  73860  8608 pts/8    Sl+  21:26   0:00 python script.py
user    32009  0.0  0.0  43128  5852 pts/8    S+   21:26   0:00 python script.py
```

If possible, without the use of the 'kill' command to resume the process.

Answer (score 2):

In the output of `ps`, a process' state `S` means **interruptible** sleep, not **uninterruptible** sleep (`D`).

When a process is in state `S`, it is waiting for the completion of some event, and can be controlled using usual manners e.g. via signals. I am not sure what you meant by *retrieval*, but as the process is in state `S`, if you want you can send whatever signal, but be sure of the outcome.

As a side note, the `l` after `S` indicates the process is multi-threaded and `+` indicates it is in the foreground process group (presumably you have run directly in the terminal like e.g. `python script.py`).